# Python, Twisted, Proxy and rotating the proxy server

Tags: python, random, proxy, twisted, web

I use the below to starting the reactor for fetching web pages...
So...all pages I fetch use the proxy once the reactor starts.  But...what if I want to rotate proxies?  How do I do that using e.g. random.choice(proxy_list)

Thanks

```
site = server.Site(proxy.ReverseProxyResource('173.000.342.234', 8800, ''))
reactor.listenTCP(8080, site)
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [the implementation](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-11.0.0/twisted/web/proxy.py#L230).  Notice where it uses the supplied IP and port to set up a new connection with `reactor.connectTCP`.  Subclass `ReverseProxyResource` and extend it to be able to connect to your randomly selected address.

Comment: Hh, I thoiught I was able to get this to work but I cant.  Hpow so I sub class?